# Applying for post-docs in mathematics: is it common to email faculty?

Tags: mathematics, job-search, postdocs, email

I am about to finish my PhD program. At this point I am trying to do a post-doc.  Is it common to email faculty members in order to see if they take post-doc students?If so what should be included in a typical email?

Comment: What does your supervisor say about guiding you here?

Comment: Customs vary from field to field.  What field are you in?

Comment: Possibly related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/23639/is-it-ethical-to-approach-a-professor-asking-for-a-unadvertised-postdoc-positi

Comment: post-doc are not students :(

Comment: @jakebeal Mathematics

Comment: I think the two answers to the question @DmitrySavostyanov linked to, pretty much cover _everything_ of relevance here.

Comment: Just for the record, i voted to close not as "too broad", but as I agree with @TheDarkSide in that this is answered well in [this old question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/23639/is-it-ethical-to-approach-a-professor-asking-for-a-unadvertised-postdoc-positi), which I re-link in case the other comment linking to it gets deleted.

Comment: Well that link provided by Dmitry Savostyanov up there barely is a proper answer for the first part of my question.and funny enough it was answered by someone who never applied for a post doc nor taken post docs discussing ethics that I couldn't care less. All I was hoping was to get some relevant answers but apparently people nowadays use democracy to shut you down ...

Comment: @BigM that question has two answers, one of them written by a professor that has been on both sides of the matter. If you want answers for the second one, you can edit this question. And ask your advisor.